# Color error with OpenGL Texture Formats

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to load an image using FreeImage and then generate an OpenGL texture. It loads the image and generates a texture, but there's an issue with the colors.

Here's the original image:
[image: original]

and here's the result:
[image: result]

Texture loading code:

```
void TextureManager::LoadTexture(std::string id, std::string filePath){

Texture tex;
tex.TextureId = 0;

FIBITMAP* image = FreeImage_Load(FreeImage_GetFileType(filePath.c_str(), 0), filePath.c_str());


if (FreeImage_GetBPP(image) != 32) {

    image = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(image);
}


FreeImage_FlipVertical(image);

tex.Width = FreeImage_GetWidth(image);
tex.Height = FreeImage_GetHeight(image);


glGenTextures(1, &tex.TextureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex.TextureId);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,tex.Width, tex.Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)FreeImage_GetBits(image));

AddTextureToMap(id, tex);

FreeImage_Unload(image);
}
```

Here's the code that's drawing it:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureManager.TextureMap[textureSelector].TextureId);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
glVertex3f(-0.75, 0.75, 0);//top left
glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
glVertex3f(0.75, 0.75, 0);//top right
glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
glVertex3f(-0.75, -0.75, 0);//bottom left

glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
glVertex3f(0.75, 0.75, 0);//top right
glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
glVertex3f(0.75, -0.75, 0);//bottom right
glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
glVertex3f(-0.75, -0.75, 0);//bottom left
glEnd();
glFinish();
```

I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the internal format in glTexImage2D, but I'm not sure which format I'd use if that's the case. My question is: Is it the format, if so, what should I use; or is there another issue that's causing this?

Comment: Try removing the `glTexEnvf` line. Also `FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits` creates a clone of the image; you need to free the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this instead

The difference is because many image formats use reverse byte order, and you should use GL_BGR_EXT or GL_BGRA_EXT image formats instead GL_RGB or GL_RGBA

```
void TextureManager::LoadTexture(std::string id, std::string filePath){

Texture tex;
tex.TextureId = 0;

FIBITMAP* image = FreeImage_Load(FreeImage_GetFileType(filePath.c_str(), 0), filePath.c_str());


if (FreeImage_GetBPP(image) != 32) {

    image = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(image);
}


FreeImage_FlipVertical(image);

tex.Width = FreeImage_GetWidth(image);
tex.Height = FreeImage_GetHeight(image);


glGenTextures(1, &tex.TextureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex.TextureId);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,tex.Width, tex.Height, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)FreeImage_GetBits(image));

AddTextureToMap(id, tex);

FreeImage_Unload(image);
}
```

Comment: So, this got me on the right track. I ended up using this:

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,tex.Width, tex.Height, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)FreeImage_GetBits(image));

I'm kinda new to OpenGL, and I'm not entirely sure Why this works though.

Comment: I have explained this moment in the answer, but not all image formats use this byte order, and if you intended to support many image formats you should somehow check the right format at runtime.

Comment: `GL_BGR` and `GL_BGRA` have been standard since OpenGL 1.2. There should be no need to use the extension form.

Answer (score 0):

If the RGBA order is not correct, you can change the color in fragment shader like

```
#version 130

uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 texCoordsVarying;
out vec4 color;

void main() {
  vec4 c2 = texture(tex, texCoordsVarying);
  color = vec4(c2.g, c2.b, c2.a, c2.r);
}
```